# Login Redirect Infinite Loop

Tags: c#, openid-connect, .net-8.0

I'm working on integrating OpenID authentication in a .NET Core application.
However, after entering login credentials, I find myself stuck in a continuous redirection loop between my application and the authentication server. Eventually, I receive an error message stating, "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again."

Current Startup:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
 {
     options.ClientId = "";
     options.Authority = "";
     options.Scope.Clear();
     options.Scope.Add("openid");
     options.Scope.Add("profile");
     options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
     options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
     options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
     options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
    
     options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
     {
         ValidateIssuer = true
     };
     options.SaveTokens = true;

     options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
     {
         OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async (context) =>
         {
             context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "";
             context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = "";
             await Task.CompletedTask;
         },
         OnTokenValidated = context =>
         {
             return Task.CompletedTask;
         },
         OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
         {
             Console.WriteLine("Token Received: " + context.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken);
             return Task.CompletedTask;
         },
         OnAuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
     };
 });
```

I've verified that Authentication and Authorization are invoked in the correct sequence.

```
 app.UseAuthentication();
 app.UseAuthorization();
```

Even in the absence of the mentioned middleware, the problem persists when I solely rely on the `[Authorize]` tag.

```
 app.Use(async (context, next) =>
 {
     var user = context.User;
     if (user == null || user.Identity == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
     {
         await context.ChallengeAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties
         {
             IsPersistent = false,
             RedirectUri = ""
         });
         return;
     }
     await next();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Website stacks often don't give you the best control over preventing redirect loops. I prefer to only trigger a redirect when the refresh token expires.

A common cause of your problem could be the use of `SameSite=none` cookies, which will not stick unless you are running over https.

The following cookie settings are the most secure and may fix your problem. They will also allow you to use http URLs on a developer workstation.

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options => { 
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
})
.AddOpenIdConnect(options => {
    options.NonceCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.CorrelationCookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}
```